# gdb says "No such file or directory" when filename contains non-ascii (unicode) character

Tags: visual-studio-code, internationalization, gdb

In VS Code, I tried to debug "구슬.cpp" with F5(gdb) and it says no such file or directory. But it works when I rename the file with "a.cpp".

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: (Relates to tool loading, not language used to compile.)

Answer (score 1):

You're pulling the filename from a program which is using a multibyte character set in the current default encoding, which is for English versions of Windows.

ASCII doesn't include any extended characters for such situation. And that's why you can't use Unicode characters as a filename, otherwise it'll obviously throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Win+R -> intl.cpl
2. Administrative tab
3. Click the Change system locale button.
4. Enable Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support
5. Reboot

It helped me.